# Ignite and Reference Tables

Tags: mysql, hibernate, ignite

Say I have 3 tables in MySQL. tables A, B and C.

Table A is:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
  `a_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`)
);
```

Table B is:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
  `b_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `b_name` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`b_id`)
);
```

Tables `A` and `B` has a many-to-many relationship so table `C` will serve as their reference table containing the primary keys of the tables `A` and `B`.

```
CREATE TABLE `table_c` (
  `a_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `b_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`,`b_id`)
);
```

When using Hibernate, there's no problem with this architecture since I can just use `@JoinTable` annotation combined with `@ManyToMany` annotation.
And Hibernate treats the uniqueness as per combination of the 1st and 2nd columns.

However, when I tried to configure a cluster by using web-console, ignite did not let me do an insert to table `C` since in one of the columns, the value already exists, when it should have been like on hibernate where the uniqueness is determined by the combination of the two columns.

Can anyone tell me how should I configure the cache for these tables?

Thanks!

**UPDATE!:**

I thought the issue was mysteriously fixed, but when I turned my logging to verbose, the insert to the reference table(composite keys) are still failing.

Ignite just allowed my application to proceed because I've setup write behind enabled. but the changes I've made doesn't really persist in my MySql persistent store.

After some investigation, I've found that Ignite is producing incorrect insert query for composite keys.

```
INSERT INTO table_c (a_id, b_id) values (5, 5) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

This query is producing a syntax error because the query is incomplete. I've managed to create a work-around for this issue by overriding Ignite's MySqlDialect and putting a check in the *updPart* variable, to produce the correct syntax if the variable is empty.

I'm not sure yet if this is a bug or limitation of Ignite.

Comment: Actually I cannot even create `table_c`, since it doesn't have any non-primary columns. But if I add another column, then the table is created and uniqueness is checked by the combination of its two key fields. Please edit your question to make it correspond to what you actually have.

Comment: table_c is actually produced by Hibernate. and that is actually what it is, I copied those **create table** statements from SQLyog's DDL information.

Comment: So, which is it? Can't you _create_ a table, or _insert_ into it?

Comment: @Denis, I tried the create table for table_c and it worked for me, not sure why it's not working on your end, I'm using MySQL 5.5

Comment: the issue is that I cannot insert a row with one of the columns having a duplicate. the uniqueness should be determined with the combination of the two columns.

Comment: Where do you try to insert data to? What role does Ignite play in your setup?

Comment: Can you show the error message of Ignite not letting you do an insert?

Comment: this is the error message, I connected to the node using DBeaver.

`SQL Error [50000]: Failed to execute DML statement [stmt=insert into table_c (a_id, b_id) values (2, 3), params=null]
  Failed to execute DML statement [stmt=insert into table_c (a_id, b_id) values (2, 3), params=null]
  Failed to execute DML statement [stmt=insert into table_c (a_id, b_id) values (2, 3), params=null]`

but when I try to query
`SELECT
*
FROM table_c c
WHERE 1=1
AND c.a_id = 2
AND c.b_id = 3
;`

No rows are returned, meaning there's no such combination

Comment: But how are Ignite tables are created? Judging by the problems, that you have, your primary key in Ignite is not composite.

Comment: Can you find more information in Ignite node log?

Comment: Hello everyone, I'm sorry for wasting your time, there seems to be a fluke with my cluster, now it works with composite primary keys without any changes. I restarted my cluster which was running on background in a linux environment and now it works fine. I'm not sure how/why/what happened that ignite is returning error 50000 before I did the restart.

thank you all for looking into this.